# ImageNet (Inception v3) model missing from Anaconda Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, imagenet

I installed Tensorflow with Anaconda Python 3.5 on Linux via the instructions to do so with pip.

Now I'm trying to follow the instructions to explore the ImageNet model which should be included.

With the `tensorflow` conda environment activated I navigated to the following directory, where I believe it should be located, and listed the files and directories. However I do not see the `imagenet` directory or the `classify_image.py` script which should be inside of it:

```
(tensorflow)root@debian:~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/models# ls image
cifar10  __init__.py  mnist  __pycache__
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe when you install Tensorflow with pip, not everything is built into `/.../site-packages/tensorflow`.

You should instead clone the github repository of TensorFlow and checkout to release 0.8 (if you built pip version 0.8).

```
git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow.git
cd tensorflow
git checkout 4b7bc31
cd tensorflow/models/image/imagenet
```

You can also directly download the v0.8 directory at [this link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/archive/v0.8.0.zip)